# SQL count the number of rows based on multiple column value

Tags: sql

I have a table as shown below. How do I write the SQL code if I want to count the number of times the row (e.g. X = A, Y = Burger) appear and return as Z? Thanks

```
Select * X, Y 
from DataBase
```

Results :

```
X   Y           Z(to be determined..)
--------------------
A   Burger      2
A   Burger      2
A   Fries       1
B   Burger      2
B   Pie         1
B   Burger      2
C   Pie         2
C   Pie         2
C   Burger      1
.   .           .
.   .           .
.   .           .
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which database system do you want to use?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You could do this with Window functions if those are supported

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select X,Y,count(*) from Table group by X,Y
```

Comment: That will not show the repeated rows that OP wants

Comment: @shree.pat18 repeated rows is a non-sense, why would you count them if you want repeated rows in resultset?!?!

Comment: Ask that to the OP. Your solution does not address the requirement as it stands

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a window function:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by x, y) as z
from DataBase t;
```